# Couchbase server: Slow GET operation on connection

Tags: couchbase

I am using couchbase-server community edition version 4.0.0. I find the below logs in the babysitter.log file repeatedly. The frequency is higher when the cluster is under load.

```
WARNING 473: Slow GET operation on connection (10.3.4.14:55846 => 10.3.9.13:11210): 4325 ms
WARNING 1057: Slow DELETE operation on connection (10.3.2.23:46152 => 10.3.9.13:11210): 1280 ms
```

I find little to no documentation for this warning log. What do these logs mean? How can I further debug the cause for slow operation?

Comment: What is the number of sessions when you see this issue?

Comment: Why did you tag this with "java"?

Comment: @Vishrant could you please help me identify the session information? I can see the number of connections using /opt/couchbase/bin/mcstat. However, I could not find session information here.

Comment: @MatthewGroves java tag was added by mistake. I have edited the question to remove it.

Comment: @Aparna this link might help https://forums.couchbase.com/t/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-list-od-active-connections/22496 also check which concurrency control method is set, and if the `locks` have been applied on the row-level or table level during the transactions. I am not aware of `couchbase` DB but these could be the starting point for investigation for any database.

Answer (score 2):

At some point, we added some logging to Couchbase to help identify bigger problems that come about from resource exhaustion by correlating to smaller problems that happen earlier.  These are some of those warnings.

They are generally safe to ignore.  It does indicate that your system might be under heavy load and perhaps the process isn't getting enough time to send/receive/handle results.

I'd also say the 4.0 version is quite old at this stage and Couchbase has been much improved and is shipping much newer runtimes.  In particular, this is coming from an erlang process, one of the things we've updated the runtime on.  I expect you'll see less of this and perhaps a little more detail.